# New installed TOR Browser does not do anything

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I have had stable TOR Browsers working excellent for years now and never had any problems after installing.
Today I did the update to TOR browser 6.0.1 and after installing , same way as always, nothing happened , in the Windows task manager not a single reference to a TOR affiliated process showed., Tried the Firefox exe in the browser folder , nothing happenened.
Is this a bug in this version?
How do I solve this ?

Comment: My works fine! I did install it on desktop (the default destination) and during install I did allow a shortcut creation. I am new into Tor and so I use all defaults during install - and just work. Maybe if you reinstalo from scrach may work for you. Good luck, and happy testing!

Comment: I have the same problem with 6.01 and Windows 10. It worked fine in past versions. I deleted 6.01 and reinstalled 5.5.5 and it works fine. I hate to use an outdated TOR, but its that or nothing!

Comment: Check your Anti-Virus logs, uninstall Trusteer Rapport if it's on your computer, check your Windows Event Logs. Let us know if theres anything about `firefox.exe` or `Tor Browser` in the aforementioned logs. We can only speculate without further information.

Comment: Checked the Windows event Logs and indeed it was the Trusteer Rapport that prevented TOR from starting up. I removed the Trusteer Rapport and it works perfect like always,  Thanks for the quick response.